# IndexPath confusion

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nsindexpath

I have several sections, and rows in each section in my table view. When I add a subview to a specific cell, using the cells indexPath, the subview is also added to other cells in other sections of my table view.

My code looks like this:

```
    let imageInCell = UIImageView()
    imageInCell.frame = CGRectMake(width - 44, 12, 20, 20)
    imageInCell.image = UIImage(named: "checked")
    imageInCell.tag == 1

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    selectedCell.addSubview(imageInCell)

  }
```

I can't make any sense out of this. The indexPath of each cell is unique, right? So why would the subview also be added to a cell in another section?

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Cells are reused, so if you add a subview to one, and it's later reused in a another row, that subview will still be there. There are tons of questions and answers about cell reuse on SO, so do some searching to see how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is due to virtualization and cell reuse.